# Why is Django on_delete rule not working?

Tags: django, django-migrations

I have two models connected via a ForeignKey sort of like this:

```
class Album(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    # ...

class Track(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, related_name='tracks', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    # ...
```

I'm writing a data migration where I try to delete some Albums:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Generated by Django 1.9.13 on 2018-12-12 14:05
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations


def forwards_func(apps, schema_editor):
    Album = apps.get_model("myapp", "Album")
    db_alias = schema_editor.connection.alias

    for album in Album.objects.using(db_alias).filter(foo='bar'):
        album.delete()

def reverse_func(apps, schema_editor):
    pass

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('myapp', '0049_blabla'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(forwards_func, reverse_func),
    ]
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 211, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()
IntegrityError: update or delete on table "Album" violates foreign key constraint "f2274d6f2be82bbff458f3e5487b1864" on table "Track"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) is still referenced from table "Track".
```

But the `on_delete` rule is there. Isn't the whole point of the delete rule to avoid errors like this? Or am I missing something? Initially I was trying a `delete` on the queryset, and I thought the `on_delete` rule wasn't supported and I had to loop through the queryset and call a delete on each instance. But apparently not even this is enough. What is the point of `on_delete` if even this doesn't work? Is there anything I can do? Thanks.

**UPDATE**: In the shell, it works. I only get the error in the migration.

Answer (score 3):

You need to allow `album` to be null indeed:

```
album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

Comment: Sorry, this is just a simplified version of my actual setup, I forgot to add this detail. I edited the question and added it. It still doesn't work though, even with the `null=True` :(

Comment: Oh, ok. Have you tried doing the same outside a migration? For example from django shell? Is the result the same?

Comment: Just tried and it works. How come it doesn't work inside the migration? Any idea?

Comment: Just bumped into a similar behavior the other day. [This part of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/migrations/#historical-models) seems to explain this behavior.