# How to add "ON DELETE" rules to existing column in a PostgreSQL database table?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-migrations

I'm using PostgreSQL in a Django project. Django does not support "on delete" rules at the database level. At the application level it allows this parameter when setting a ForeignKey for a model, but it's only used to [emulate the behavior](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete) when deleting instances. I'm trying to run a data migration that deletes a set of rows from a table which is reference by another one. The models look something like this:

```
class Album(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    # ...

class Track(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, related_name='tracks', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    # ...
```

I don't know if this behavior is supposed to be emulated in `delete` calls performed on querysets, or only model instances. For me neither is working. The cleanest solution in my mind would be to add a RunSQL that adds a "ON DELETE SET NULL" rule on the `Track.album` foreign key at the database level (before the RunPython that actually tries to delete the Album rows). The problem is that Django seems to create a foreign key constraint with a dynamic name, so if I drop that constraint by name and create another one, I'm afraid the migration may fail when I deploy. Isn't there a simple way to add the rule (or drop/create the constraint) by column name?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What are you doing exactly and what isn’t working in relation to the models you showed? If you perform a data migration that deletes Album objects using Django querysets then the corresponding Tracks will have their ForeignKey set to null. Isn’t that what you want?

Comment: That's what I want, but that is not what happens. I get an integrity error instead (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53765114/). In any case, I think it would be cleaner to have this behavior enforced at the database level, rather than emulated by Django.